# Swipe in Android 2.2 browser blocks/freezes web app

Tags: android, block, freeze, swipe

I have a simple web app that consists of a circle moving around. When I do a swipe, the app freezes and the circle stops moving, and I have to do another swipe/tap to set it in motion again. This only happens in Andoid 2.2 devices (2.3 works OK). Does anyone know why this happens? How can I avoid this?

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="touch.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
         This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="300">
     This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;  
var ctx;
var x = 400;
var y = 300;
var dx = 2;
var dy = 4;
var WIDTH = 400;
var HEIGHT = 300; 

function circle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}


function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {

    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove);
    document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
  rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
  circle(x, y, 10);

  if (x + dx > WIDTH || x + dx < 0)
    dx = -dx;
  if (y + dy > HEIGHT || y + dy < 0)
    dy = -dy;

  x += dx;
  y += dy;
}

init();
</script>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

touch.js

```
var triggerElementID = null; 
var fingerCount = 0;
var startXPosition = 0;
var startYPosition = 0;
var currentXPosition = 0;
var currentYPosition = 0;
var minLength = 72; 
var swipeLength = 0;
var swipeDirection = null;

function touchStart(event,passedName) {
event.preventDefault();
fingerCount = event.touches.length;

if (fingerCount == 1 ) {
    startXPosition = event.touches[0].pageX;
    startYPosition = event.touches[0].pageY;
    triggerElementID = passedName ? passedName : this.id;
} else {
    touchCancel(event);
}
}

function touchMove(event) {
event.preventDefault();

if (event.touches.length == 1 ) {
    currentXPosition = event.touches[0].pageX;
    currentYPosition = event.touches[0].pageY;
} else {
    touchCancel(event);
}
}


function touchEnd(event) {
try {
    event.preventDefault();     
    if ( fingerCount == 1 && currentXPosition != 0 ) {
        currentXPosition = event.touches[0].pageX;
        currentYPosition = event.touches[0].pageY;

        swipeLength = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(currentXPosition - startXPosition,2) + Math.pow(currentYPosition - startYPosition,2)));

        if ( swipeLength >= minLength ) {
            caluculateAngle();
        }
    }
} finally {
    touchCancel(event);
}
}


function touchCancel(event) {
fingerCount = 0;
startXPosition = 0;
startYPosition = 0;
currentXPosition = 0;
currentYPosition = 0;
swipeLength = 0;
swipeDirection = null;
triggerElementID = null;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried canvas on webview,  it will cause high CPU load and high memory